# Openshift Origin 1.4 release plan

Tags: openshift

Does anyone know the release schedule of openshift origin 1.4 ?

As I know 1.4 is in alpha now, but when is the final release ?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift Origin release follow the Kubernetes release they are based on. According to:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/milestones

the kubernetes 1.4 release is past due at this point and thus why there would be a delay in OpenShift Origin 1.4.

So watch for Kubernetes releases and once a version of it is released then if all goes well the Origin release shouldn't be far after.